# Portability of $BASHPID

Tags: bash

I found some inconsistent behavior of `$BASHPID` as below:

```
# On Mac Yosemite
echo $BASH_VERSION ${BASH_VERSINFO[5]} $BASHPID
# => 3.2.57(1)-release x86_64-apple-darwin14

# On Ubuntu
echo $BASH_VERSION ${BASH_VERSINFO[5]} $BASHPID
# => 4.3.11(1)-release x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 29134
```

The `$BASHPID` is not present for Mac OSX, is it not safe to use it to write portable script?

Comment: The version on OS X is quite old and with high probability do not support this variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The builtin variable `$BASHPID` was introduced in bash version 4.0.

See the file `NEWS` in the bash source code:

```
 397 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 398 This is a terse description of the new features added to bash-4.0 since
 399 the release of bash-3.2.  As always, the manual page (doc/bash.1) is
 400 the place to look for complete descriptions.
 401 
 402 1.  New Features in Bash
 403 
 ...
 410 c.  There is a new variable, $BASHPID, which always returns the process id of
 411     the current shell.
```

Comment: Notice this release is back in 2009, surprisingly Yosemite still ships version 3.*.

Comment: @steveyang One possible explanation for why Apple continues to ship out-of-date software is [here](http://meta.ath0.com/2012/02/05/apples-great-gpl-purge/).